# Suspend setTimeout refresh function when client is idle. Enable function when client is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

An existing refresh function that I don't wan't to touch (if possible). It refreshes a table in page.

I need to suspend the refresh function if the client is idle / inactive.

If the client is active the original refresh function returns to the way it was before being suspended.

```
//SUSPEND THIS FUNCTION IF CLIENT IS IDLE
//ENABLE THIS FUNCTION WHEN CLIENT IS ACTIVE
    function refreshTable() {

        window.clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);

        $("body").append("<p>refreshTable every 5 seconds.</p>");
    }
    var timer = window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 0);



    function idleClientCheck() {
        var t;
        window.onload = resetTimer;
        window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
        window.onmousedown = resetTimer;
        window.onclick = resetTimer;
        window.onscroll = resetTimer;
        window.onkeypress = resetTimer;


        function isNotIdle() {
            setTimeout(timer);
            //alert('isNotIdle');
        }

        function isIdle() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            alert('isIdle');
        }

        function resetTimer() {
            clearTimeout(t);
            //MY LOGIC ERROR
            t = setInterval(isNotIdle, 9999);

            //THIS WORKS LIKE I WANT. BUT refreshTable() DOES NOT
            //RESTART AGAIN WHEN CLIENT IS ACTIVE
            t = setInterval(isIdle, 15000);
        } 
    }
    idleClientCheck();
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/zExPwX)

Comment: You can use `clearInterval()` to stop the interval running, but what do you consider an 'active' user?

Comment: If the client has moved mouse, clicked etc within 15 seconds I consider them 'active' or 'not idle'. 

15 seconds will be changed to 15 - 30 minutes later (in production).

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be easily refactored into something that makes a bit more sense, when you realized that all your need is **two timers**:

1. Timer 1, say `refreshTimer`, simply iteratively invokes itself to refresh the table
2. Timer 2, say `idleTimer`, checks how long the user has been idle. This timer is reset whenever a specific event is fired from the `window` object, as per your question's requirements

---

### Basic timer settings

With that in mind, we can set up two global timers:

```
// Global timers
var refreshTimer = null,
    idleTimer = null;
```

We can also store the timeouts somewhere, so that they don't clutter our functions with magic constants :) `refreshDuration` is the interval you want to call the refresh function, while `idleDuration` is the duration you use to determine if the user is inactive:

```
// Some settings
var refreshDuration = 5000,  // You can change this!
    idleDuration = 3000;     // You can change this!
```

> p/s: You have noted in your question that you wanted to wait for 15s (i.e. `15000ms`), but for testing purposes I have reduced it.

---

### The refresh timer: self-invoking function that refreshes content

To mimic a `window.setInterval` function for the `freshTimer` callback, we simply define a `refresh()` function, which within itself starts a new timeout and invokes itself again:

```
var refresh = function() {
  $("body").append("<p>refreshTable every 5 second.</p>");

  // Call itself
  refreshTimer = window.setTimeout(refresh, refreshDuration);
};
```

---

### The idle timer: checking for user (in)activity

For the idle timer, what you want to do is not to use `window.onload` to bind events. That is because this can only be run once, and if you have other `window.onload` statements on your page, you will risk overwriting them. Use `.addEventListener` instead. So, what we can do is store all the events you want to listen to in an array, and bind them iteratively using [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

In each of these event callbacks, you want to clear both global timers, because:

1. You want to cancel the self-invoking refresh function, and
2. You want to restart the countdown towards a "user is idle" state

And then you simply restart the `idleTimer` in the same callback. The `idleTimer` will simply restart the self-invoking refresh function when it times out:

```
var idleClientCheck = function() {

  // These events will trigger a new countdown
  var events = ['load', 'mousemove', 'mousedown', 'click', 'scroll', 'keypress'];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

    // Use IIFE to bind correct event on the fly
    (function() {
      var e = events[i];
      window.addEventListener(e, function() {
        // When these events are triggered, we cancel refreshTimer and idleTimer
        window.clearTimeout(refreshTimer);
        window.clearTimeout(idleTimer);

        console.log('Refresh timer cancelled by ' + e + ', will restart in ' + idleDuration + 'ms');

        // We restart idleTimer
        // idleTimer simply fires refresh() when time runs out
        idleTimer = window.setTimeout(refresh, idleDuration);
      });
    })(i);

  }
};

idleClientCheck();
```

Combining all these at once, and you get a functional snippet:

```js
// Global timers
var refreshTimer = null,
    idleTimer = null;
    
// Some settings
var refreshDuration = 5000,
    idleDuration = 3000;

// refresh() is simply a method with a self-invoking to mimic window.setInterval
var refresh = function() {
  $("body").append("<p>refreshTable every 5 second.</p>");
  
  // Call itself
  refreshTimer = window.setTimeout(refresh, refreshDuration);
};

// idleClientCheck() runs its own timer to check for idle client
var idleClientCheck = function() {

  // These events will trigger a new countdown
  var events = ['load', 'mousemove', 'mousedown', 'click', 'scroll', 'keypress'];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
  
    // Use IIFE to bind correct event on the fly
    (function() {
      var e = events[i];
      window.addEventListener(e, function() {
        // When these events are triggered, we cancel refreshTimer and idleTimer
        window.clearTimeout(refreshTimer);
        window.clearTimeout(idleTimer);

        console.log('Refresh timer cancelled by ' + e + ', will restart in ' + idleDuration + 'ms');

        // We restart idleTimer
        // idleTimer simply fires refresh() when time runs out
        idleTimer = window.setTimeout(refresh, idleDuration);
      });
    })(i);
    
  }
};

idleClientCheck();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very thorough answer. Although I wanted the other way around so if the client is (in)active / idle for 15 seconds or more the refresh stops until the client moves mouse, clicks etc.
The timer idea is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

its work for me ..I have checked and you can also check this in "TryitEditor" of W3Schools

```
<script>
 //SUSPEND THIS FUNCTION IF CLIENT IS IDLE
//ENABLE THIS FUNCTION WHEN CLIENT IS ACTIVE
    function refreshTable() {

        window.clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);

        $("body").append("<p>refreshTable every 5 seconds.</p>");
    }
    var timer = window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 0);



    function idleClientCheck() {
        var t1;
         var t2;
        window.onload = resetTimer;
        window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
        window.onmousedown = resetTimer;
        window.onclick = resetTimer;
        window.onscroll = resetTimer;
        window.onkeypress = resetTimer;


        function isNotIdle() {

            timer = window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
            //setTimeout(timer);
            //alert('isNotIdle');
             $("body").append("<p>isNotIdle</p>");
        }

        function isIdle() {
        clearTimeout(t1);
            //timer = null;
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
             $("body").append("<p>isIdle</p>");
            //alert('isIdle');
        }

        function resetTimer() {
            clearTimeout(t1);
            clearTimeout(t2);
            t1 = setInterval(isNotIdle, 9999);
            t2 = setInterval(isIdle, 15000);
        } 
    }
    idleClientCheck();
</script>
```

Comment: just added jquery link in your header before test it